# Should hat dash continue after christmas?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign, winterbash

The title resumes the question...

So I officially request that hat dash continues after Christmas time.

What do you think?

Comment: [bydesign] - hats have become a one-a-year Xmas/Winter/Summer celebration and are packed up shortly into the new year.

Comment: Oh hello post that was 9 years ago lol

Comment: Yeah sorry for the necro, I'm just (slowly) working through status-tagging old [bugs] and [feature-requests] that are resolved.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think they work well for the season and as a way to boost traffic / interest a bit, however I don't like it as a long term "thing". I would get tired of them quickly, lets just keep it as an interesting holiday perk.

Comment: ...though I bet someone might be willing to write a greasemonkey script for those who can't let go

Answer (score 12):

**I'd vote to remove it altogether after the event is over.**

I've always liked the simplicity of GSE and the fact that your rep & badges are your indicator of awesomeness. The moment we start using hats as a standard metric for awesomeness, we start to venture into the scary world of "things that look like forum signatures", and the site becomes less elegant as a result.

I tolerate it as a temporary thing, and I know I could just say that "I hate hats" in the footer. However, I think showing the hats is a bad choice of default functionality.

**If you insist on keeping them, make them an opt-in piece.** "Show me my hat and everyone elses" means that, to new users, the site remains elegant & less distracting. Others can forum0ify it at their discretion.

Answer (score 8):

Make it into a badge.

Perhaps even 3 levels:

bronze hatdash - participated in a hatdash (assuming there's more)
silver hatdash - owner of X hats
gold hatdash - owner of X+Y hats

Hide the hats for the rest of the year unless there's more hat dash events.

Comment: I like this idea best.

Comment: Yes please. Site-specific badges are [already a thing](http://stackapps.com/badges/60/api-evangelist), so yeah. Also, the gold badge should be awarded for 16 or more hats (Pokémon hat). And I'm not just saying this because I have 16 hats. Okay, I totally am.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by "continue" it.  I'd support allowing hats to be earned after the holidays and allowing us to wear hats year round.  I don't want this to turn into TF2 and have a new hat for every new game that comes out, though.  That's way too much work to ask of the admins and graphic artists.

Comment: You could simply offload much of that work to the community, a la TF2...

Comment: I would say major releases should have their hat, not every game evar.

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be some benefit from allowing the *wearing* of hats all the time, but I think the *earning* of hats should be tied to some event.

Whether that event is Christmas, Easter, Graduation from High School or the release of an eagerly anticipated game is up to the team.

Comment: I hate it so much when TF2 does that and I missed the relevant windows of opportunity :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd kind of like the idea; I want to keep my unicorn, dammit!  ...But after a while, it probably wouldn't be "special" any more...  :/

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat like the idea, as it's a nice visible way to perhaps show where one's interests are at the moment based on what hat you choose to wear (assuming people would wear the hat for whatever game...which could be flat wrong in many cases).

The bar for the hats seem abysmal compared to even a bronze game badge, so if this is longer-term, it would be nice to see the standards come up a bit.

This is probably a burden on the admins/artists as Dave mentions, but we might as well rip off TF2's community model as well.  I'd like to see some actual QC though (by some SE employee), as people could turn out total crap and if it's some simple democratic vote, would be easy enough to pass it.