# What should happen at the end of Hat Dash?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Hat Dash was always meant to be a fun, temporary thing, and it seems that [mostly people agree with this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/should-hat-dash-continue-after-christmas).  However, it seems like there should be *some* sort of permanent artifact, especially for people who worked hard at it.  So, what should it be?  Here are some ideas people have suggested, but feel free to add your own:

- [a badge](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3579/3)
- a special hatdash [flair](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/flair) image you can put in your "about me"
- a permanent hat rack at hatdash.com
- a t-shirt
- a hat (as in, real-world wearable)
- ...something else?

Suggest your favorite idea in the answers (including one of the above) so people can vote on it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> a permanent hat rack at hatdash.com

I vote for this.
It's not intrusive on the site, it would make that domain useful past the deadline, and you could collect them if there was another hatdash in the future.

Comment: This is now in the works

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea of a real-world wearable hat.

Something with a clever saying mentioning Hat Dash 2011 on the front and a link to gaming on the back, perhaps? Depending on the style of the hat that might not work, but hat design is probably worth a separate meta thread anyway if this idea flies.

Answer (score 2):

I want a "certificate."  I think I asked for this before.  Something silly where you can print it out and hang it up or set it as your desktop pattern or whatever, and it says how many hats you got, and perhaps shows your gravatar wearing the hat of your choice.

Maybe that's part of this secondary website that also shows you the hat rack or what have you.

I wouldn't support any permanent changes of the site design/badges/etc for this, as I consider it to be a silly, fun, holiday time waster.  Most everything about this site is accessible to anyone who joins at any time, and making something that is only for people who were here before a certain date seems mean.

Comment: There is a precedent: the Beta badge.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the beta badge.  Darn beta badge, grrrrrr.