# Hat Dash Ownership

Tags: discussion, winterbash

I see the hats site shows January 6 as the deadline, then they can no longer be achieved... so is a hat going to stay with your profile forever?  It can be switched later on, correct?

Answer (score 4):

All traces of hats *here* will vanish forever come January 6th (unless there is something else hat related in the works).  However, there will still be ["a permanent hat rack at hatdash.com"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3595/5029).